# Is there an idiom that means "taking revenge for X"?

Tags: idiom-request

I know the idiomatic phrase "getting back at someone", but the issue here is that it's synonymous with "taking revenge against someone" instead "taking revenge for an action done against me". Are there idioms that mean the latter?

For example:

> I will get my revenge for the things you've done to me.

Comment: you cannot really separate the action from the author, when talking about revenge. Can you give an example where you revenge against the action, but the original author remains unhurt?

Comment: *I will [**avenge** the wrongs](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22avenge+the+wrongs%22) done to me* (25,000 hits in Google Books) You ***take, exact** revenge **for** [some harmful action]* ***on, against** [the wrongdoer],* where both "objects" normally require some form of preposition. But there's no need for a preposition when you ***avenge [some crime]*** (a construction which wouldn't normally involve you mentioning the "someone" who committed that crime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you've written is correct. Although most idioms for "revenge" also work for "revenge for", some good examples include:

> I'll have my revenge for that
>
> I'll get you back for that
>
> You'll get your comeuppance for that (uncommon/dialectic)
>
> I'll be avenged for that
>
> This is payback for that

*(Where "that" is whatever you're getting revenge for, obviously)*